# Moving to pytorch from tensorflow: practical considerations regarding inputs

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

As TF 2.0 looms and with it the certainty of having to rewrite or throw away most of my scripts, I am considering switching to pytorch. I initially liked TF for its low-level API — I think it is becoming a complete mess by trying to become everything at once. Also, the library is a hell to compile on Windows. Using a trained model from C++ on Windows has become virtually impossible because of that.

I have looked a bit at pytorch, I like that its API is simple and consistent, and Windows users are greeted with C++ librairies straight from the website. Frankly I feel they are flirting with me. I thought pytorch was a python wrapper around a Lua library but I have clearly been mistaken.

One of the strength (maybe *the* selling point to me) of TF is its input pipeline. Whether from the old `tf.queue` days or the more recent `tf.data` framework, TF always tried to propose an input pipeline that is able to preprocess and prefetch input data to device memory concurrently to training. It is all pretty well explained on [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets).

This efficient input pipeline is important in practice to achieve a high utilization of GPUs, esp. when I/O operations and data augmentation is a bit heavy. Is there an equivalent in pytorch? I have not seen such an example in the tutorials. I saw a [`Dataset` class in the "Data Loading and Processing" tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html#dataset-class) but it looks like standard python, so I am assuming it cannot run concurrently to training.

If anyone with experience with both could weigh in on that topic, and also perhaps on other topics such as using a trained model from C++, I'd be glad to hear it.

I know I would be flamed on stackoverflow for asking this kind of broad question, I hope it's okay here.

Comment: Did you end up migrating?